# How to read Math Equations from Powerpoint and write it to Word document in C#

Tags: c#, math, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I am developing a PowerPoint extraction tool since march 2014 which extracts the words or paragraphs from PowerPoint and write it to word document. It has been developed. During the testing. we found that **Math Equation** has not being fetched from PowerPoint slide.
I am using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint.dll** library. i am reading file such as given below.

```
  var powerPoint = new Application {WindowState=PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized};                
  var oPresSet = powerPoint.Presentations;
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(pptName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
  var str = oPres.Slides[1].NotesPage.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
```

Here is screenshot of input of PPT.
[image]

but i want to read math equation which have in the PowerPoint slide.
i tried to use these MathZones and get_MathZones but i didn't get much about it that how to use MathZones proerety. On other hand, get_MathZones method gives the same garbled text. i used the get_MathZones method such as given below.

```
 var strObj = oPres.Slides[1].NotesPage.Shapes[2].TextFrame2.TextRange.MathZones.get_MathZones();
var str = strObj.Text;
```

Here is screenshot of output of ppt as garbled text.
[image]

I just want to read **Math Equation** from PowerPoint then want to write it in word document programatically. Here firstly i am not able to read Math Equation. Suggest me any solutions.

Comment: how to use it in c#?

Comment: Can we use MS office math equation using programmetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i got the [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/24d331da-93cd-4749-a9b7-8c013298cc72/how-to-read-math-equations-from-powerpoint-and-write-it-to-word-document-in-c?forum=exceldev#8f6f6196-589b-4159-8a94-7bb743f7c50a) and that is the concept of **Copy and Paste**.